# In C how do i get the path of a symlink (I mean the path to the symlink not to the target)?

Tags: c, path, symlink

In C, how do I get the path of a symlink (I mean the path to the symlink, not to the target)?

Because when I use `realpath()` with the name of the symlink as argument, I get the path to the target.

Is there a way to get the path to the symlink itself and not the target?

Comment: That depends on the platform, not the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux (and other POSIX systems) you might use [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html)